# Web.Config transformations in the debugger

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

When you run an application in the debugger, it appears to not apply the transformations to the web.config based on your build selection.  Is this the case or am I missing something?  It appears to be working just fine if I publish to local IIS, just does not seem to work in the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after saving the web.config changes then applying full refresh "ctrl + F5" (actually not always required) to the browser you are suppose to get the effect of the changes.

also check the existance of:

`<compilation debug="true">`

in the web.config file.

Comment: That was the problem, I did not remove the debug="false" from the transform.